# "Out of memory" error when processing large recordsets

Tags: sql-server, ado

I have a Windows Script host script which executes a Stored Procedure in our database and returns back a large recordset with about 225 columns (the column count does vary depending on the query, it may well get larger in the future).

```
var adUseServer = 2;
var adUseClient = 3;
var adOpenForwardOnly = 0;
var adLockReadOnly = 1;


var dbc = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.connection")

dbc.connectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=MYDBSERVER;Database=MYDB;uid=USER;Pwd=PASSWORD;"
dbc.CursorLocation = adUseClient
dbc.connectionTimeout = 3600
dbc.commandTimeout = 3600
dbc.open

// Setup test table
WScript.echo( "Setting table..." );
dbc.execute( "IF OBJECT_ID(N'export_test', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE export_test;;" );
dbc.execute( "create table export_test ( channelID int )" );

// Changing to 130 works (for me)
for( var n = 1; n < 131; n++ )
{
    dbc.execute( "alter table export_test ADD test_" + n + " NVARCHAR(4000) DEFAULT '0' not null" );
}



WScript.echo( "Starting query..." );

var rsData = serverQuery( "Select * from export_test" )

WScript.echo( "Starting loop..." );

var count = 0;
while( rsData.eof == 0 )
{
    WScript.echo( count++ );
    rsData.moveNext();
}

WScript.echo( "All done" );



function serverQuery( sql )
{
    var rsData = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.recordset");
    rsData.CursorLocation = adUseServer;
    rsData.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly;
    rsData.LockType = adLockReadOnly;
    rsData.MaxRecords = 1;  // This makes no difference
    rsData.open( sql, dbc );

    return rsData;
}
```

When I execute this query using a client cursor, I get an "Out of memory" error; if I execute with a server cursor I get a "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation" error.

I have tried reducing the data down so not many rows are being returned and the problem persists.

I was going to try 'paging' the results, but I fear after doing the work that it wont help as I have tried reducing the returned rows and that didnt help, so I think it may be the large number of columns (which is dynamic and may well get more and more over time) being the fundamental cause of the issue.

After reading on SO and other sites, I have tried changing the database log file size to "unrestricted growth" but it wont let me and keeps reverting back to 'max size of 2GB', but thats a different problem (I think) as its currently nowhere near that si.

Does anyone have any futher ideas or insight into this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right I basically summised that it was a limitation somewhere, so what I did was create a COM object to offload this work and return back a JSON or XML version of the result data which I could use within my script.

For anyone that cares, below is the C# code (apologies if its a bit naff, I have no-one to code review with anymore as I am a sole dev now):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Xml;

/*
 * To create strong name key for signing: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\sn" -k SQLInterchange_Key.snk"
 */


namespace SQLInterchange
{
  [Guid( "4E97C259-80EC-40dc-8F7D-DB56BE9F123E" )]
  public interface ISQLInterchange
  {
    [DispId( 1 )]
    bool Open( string databaseServer, string databaseName, string userID, string userPassword );

    [DispId( 2 )]
    void Close();

    [DispId( 3 )]
    bool ExecuteRecordset( string selCommand );

    [DispId( 4 )]
    void CloseRecordset();

    [DispId( 5 )]
    bool Execute( string selCommand );

    [DispId( 6 )]
    string GetJSONData();

    [DispId( 7 )]
    string GetXMLData( string recordElementName, bool encoded );
  }


  // Events interface Database_COMObjectEvents 
  [Guid( "31A125AA-81D5-495b-86E6-7A4B24B08BAA" ),
    InterfaceType( ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch )]
  public interface SQLInterchange_Events
  {
  }


  [Guid( "6B0B6A04-3BAF-4e14-9770-A0C10425E2CE" ),
    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
    ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(SQLInterchange_Events))]
  public class Connection : ISQLInterchange
  {
    private SqlConnection _connection = null;
    private SqlDataReader _reader = null;

    public Connection()
    {
    }

    public bool Open( string databaseServer, string databaseName, string userID, string userPassword  )
    {
      // no need to throw as it throws a com compatible exception automatically

      string myConnectString = "user id=" + userID + ";password=" + userPassword +";Database=" + databaseName + ";Server=" + databaseServer + ";Connect Timeout=30";
      _connection = new SqlConnection( myConnectString );
      _connection.Open();

      return true;
    }

    public bool ExecuteRecordset( string selCommand )
    {
      if( _reader != null )
        _reader.Close();

      SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand( selCommand );
      myCommand.Connection = _connection;
      myCommand.CommandTimeout = 3600;
      myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      _reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
      return true;
    }


    public bool Execute( string selCommand )
    {
      if( _reader != null )
        _reader.Close();

      SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand( selCommand, _connection );
      myCommand.CommandTimeout = 3600;
      int rows = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      return true;
    }


    public void Close()
    {
      if( _connection != null )
        _connection.Close();
    }


    public void CloseRecordset()
    {
      if( _reader != null )
        _reader.Close();
    }


    public string GetJSONData()
    {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.Append( "[" );

      if( _reader != null )
      {
        int count = _reader.FieldCount;

        StringBuilder sbRecord = new StringBuilder();
        while( _reader.Read() )
        {

          if( sbRecord.Length > 0 )
          {
            sbRecord.Append( "," );
          }

          sbRecord.Append( "{" );

          // get the results of each column
          for( int n = 0; n < count; n++ )
          {
            string name = _reader.GetName( n );
            string data = Convert.ToString( _reader[ n ] );

            sbRecord.Append( "\"" + _safeJSONElementName( name ) + "\":\"" );

            sbRecord.Append( _safeJSON( data ) );

            sbRecord.Append( "\"" );

            if( n + 1 < count )
            {
              sbRecord.Append( "," );
            }
          }

          sbRecord.Append( "}" );
        }

        sb.Append( sbRecord.ToString() );
      }

      sb.Append( "]" );

      return sb.ToString();
    }


    public string GetXMLData( string recordElementName, bool encoded )
    {
      _lt = "<";
      _gt = ">";

      if( encoded )
      {
        _lt = "&lt;";
        _gt = "&gt;";
      }

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

      if( _reader != null )
      {
        int count = _reader.FieldCount;

        while( _reader.Read() )
        {
          _addXMLElement( sb, recordElementName, 1, true );

          // get the results of each column
          for( int n = 0; n < count; n++ )
          {
            string name = _reader.GetName( n );
            string data = Convert.ToString( _reader[ n ] );

            _addXMLElement( sb, name, 2, false );

            sb.Append( _escapeXML( data ) );

            _addXMLElement( sb, "/" + name, 0, true );
          }

          _addXMLElement( sb, "/" + recordElementName, 1, true );
        }
      }

      return sb.ToString();
    }


    private string _safeJSON( string s )
    {
      s = s.Replace( "\n", "\\n" );
      s = s.Replace( "\r", "\\r" );
      s = s.Replace( "\t", "\\t" );
      s = s.Replace( "\"", "\\\"" );
      return s;
    }

    private string _safeJSONElementName( string s )
    {
      s = s.Replace( ".", "_" );
      s = s.Replace( " ", "_" );
      return s;
    }


    private string _lt = "<";
    private string _gt = ">";

    private void _addXMLElement( StringBuilder sb, string s, int tabs, bool last )
    {
      for( int n = 0; n < tabs; n++ )
      {
        sb.Append( "\t" );
      }
      sb.Append( _lt );
      sb.Append( s );
      sb.Append( _gt );
      if( last ) sb.Append( "\n" );
    }

    private string _escapeXML( string unescaped )
    {
      XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
      var node = doc.CreateElement("root");
      node.InnerText = unescaped;
      return node.InnerXml;
    }
  }

}
```